# Finding the transformation matrix of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am given a linear map $T_1: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^2}$ with $T_1(1,2) = (0,-1)$ and $T_1(-1,-1) = (2,1)$ and asked to solve it but i have no idea how to solve but the answer is $T_1:(x,y) = (2y-4x,-x)$.

I assumed that $(1,2)$ and $(-1,-1)$ are basis vectors and tried to find the co-ordinates with respect to ths basis but this is not the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
 c & d \\
\end{array}
\right).\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & -1 \\
 2 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 2 \\
 -1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
so
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
 c & d \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 2 \\
 -1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right).\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & -1 \\
 2 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)^{-1}=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -4 & 2 \\
 -1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
in agreeance with the solution you wrote

Comment: Yes it's my mistake , i edit the question and thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I also disagree with the solution,

Note, 
$$
T_1(0,1)=T_1(1,2)+T_1(-1,-1)=(0,-1)+(2,1)=(2,0)
$$
and 
$$
T_1(1,0)=-(T_1(1,2)+2T_1(-1,-1)=-((0,-1)+2(2,1))=(-4,-1)
$$
So 
$$
T_1(x,y)=xT_1(1,0)+yT_1(0,1)=(-4x+2y,-x)
$$

Comment: Yes it's my mistake , i edit the question and thanks for the answer.

Comment: @LuaiGhunim now we agree :)